# Configuration issues trying to get 2 apps to work on nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, deployment, server, certificate

I'm trying to deploy a Vue app with a Strapi backend on nginx.

I created 2 files in sites-available, and symlinks in sites-enabled.
I also got an ssl-cert from let’s encrypt.

When I visit the domain, I see nothing in the browser, and have a 304 and some 404 errors in the network tab. When I visit domain.com/admin, I see a strapi splashscreen, but not the login form that I need.

When I go directly to the ip, I see the frontend app, and when I visit :1337/admin, I see the backend. Any idea what I’m doing wrong here?

Thanks

my frontend.conf looks like this

```
server {
    # Listen HTTP
    listen 80;
    server_name companynamefront.com;
    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    # Listen HTTPS
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name companynamefront.com;
    # SSL config
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/new.companyname.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/new.companyname.com/privkey.pem;                                                    
# Static Root
location / {
    root /var/www/html/companyname/v-frontend/dist;
}
}
```

and the backend.conf looks like this

```
server {
    # Listen HTTP
    listen 80;
    server_name companyname.com;
    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    # Listen HTTPS
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name companyname.com;
    # SSL config
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/new.companyname.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/new.companyname.com/privkey.pem;
    # Static Root
    location / {
        root /var/www/html/companyname/backend/build;
    }
    # Strapi API and Admin
    location /admin/ {
        rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```